# How to insert and save data in an array from a Text file? ( In java)

Tags: java, arrays, text-files

How do I insert the below data in an array so that I get positions of those elements in the array?

```
1 37
4 10
9 22
21 21
28 56
36 8
51 16
71 20
80 20
98 -20
95 -20
93 -20
87 -63
64 -4
62 -43
56 -3
49 -38
47 -21
16 -10
```

So I tried this:

```java
int[] gameBoard;
      
String fileName;
  
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("p3input.txt"));
fileName="in.txt"; 
int numLadders = 0;
int numChutes = 0;
int blank=0;
int index=0;
int value;
      
index = in.nextInt();
      
gameBoard = new int[index];
while (in.hasNextInt()) {
    index = in.nextInt();
    value = in.nextInt();
    gameBoard[index] = value;
    if (value > 0) {
        numLadders++;
    }
    else if(value < 0) {
        numChutes++;
    }
    else {
        blank++;
    }        
}
```

But I want to read and get the elements from that file in an array like: `array[4,10,5,6]`.

Comment: What did you try to do?

Comment: I tried saving in an array, like array[1,37,4,10] something like that but not able to.

Comment: Post the code. Let us see what you did and what parts are missing/failing.

Comment: have you tried `text.split(" ")` ?

Comment: just added the code of what I am doing

Answer (score 0):

The input file contains two columns `index` and `value` and existing code creates an empty array `gameBoard` and saves the values at appropriate indexes, so the resulting array looks as follows:

```
[0, 37, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22,... ]
```

Also, here initial `index` should be 99 - the maximum number in the first column (98) + 1 because array indexes start from 0, and the `gameBoard` will be sparse and contain many zeroes.

---

If you want to store both index and value in the same `gameBoard` array, the size of the gameboard should be equal to the doubled number of pairs (for the given example `2 * 19 = 38`)

```java
index = 2 * in.nextInt(); // number of pairs

gameBoard = new int[index];
index = 0;
boolean readValue = false;
while (in.hasNextInt() && index < gameBoard.length) {
    gameBoard[index] = in.nextInt();

    if (readValue) {
        value = gameBoard[index];
        if (value > 0) {
            numLadders++;
        }
        else if(value < 0) {
            numChutes++;
        }
        else {
            blank++;
        }        
    }
    index++;
    readValue = !readValue;
}
```

In this case, `gameBoard` will look like this:

```
[1, 37, 4, 10, 9, 22, 21, 21, 28, 56, ...
```

Also, it might be better to use a `Map<Integer, Integer>` instead of array for `gameBoard` because it would allow fast access by "index" key:

```java
{1=37, 4=10, 9=22, 21=21, 28=56, ... }
```